# Wordpress "update_option" analog in Joomla?

Tags: wordpress, joomla

Wordpress has this nice function [update_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option). it is a nice way to store some settings for plugins and widgets. Have Joomla something like this? Or should i create the table in the database to store couple of options? (I am talking about the options that i don't want user to be able to change in the backend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Back end options are built in, you define them in the XML manifest for the extension. Here's a tutorial I dug up on Google - http://www.vergegraphics.com/blog/joomla/58-extending-joomla-modules-with-parameters

Here is a list of standard parameters - http://docs.joomla.org/Standard_parameter_types